# Why is vim not remembering my position in a file between runs?

Tags: linux, vim

I'm using vim 7.2.330 on 64 bit ubuntu 10.04, sometime in the last week every time I reopen a file it places the cursor at the top of the file.  I can see in ~/.viminfo where it's saving the last position used, but it doesn't seem to be honoring it.

Any ideas?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/774560/2014893

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> to jump through the 'jumps'.

you also add something to your .vimrc to jump to that cursor position automatically, read more at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_cursor_to_file_position_in_previous_editing_session:

```
" VimTip 80: Restore cursor to file position in previous editing session
" for unix/linux/solaris
set viminfo='10,\"100,:20,%,n~/.viminfo

" only for windows [give some path to store the line number info]
"set viminfo='10,\"100,:20,%,nc:\\Winnt\\_viminfo
 au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g`\"" | endif
```

Comment: What's bothering me is I'm certain it used to remember the position and I didn't do anything in .vimrc to make it do so.  And I know my Fedora system it remembers the position in the file without anything in the .vimrc to tell it to.

Comment: This is probably due to the fact that some packagers/distributions set the included example vimrc as the system-wide default vimrc, and some don't.  That example vimrc contains an autocmd much like the one above.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, I have observed the same behavior, but with a very different diagnosis.

When my /home/... partition became full, .viminfo was unable to be written, so those file positions were never stored. Once I cleared up some space, viminfo was positioning my editor again.

Comment: Also check for permissions+ownership of the ~/.viminfo file

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [:help last-position-jump](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#last-position-jump):

> This `autocommand` jumps to the last known position in a file just after opening it, if the `'"'` mark is set:
>
> ```
> :au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g`\"" | endif
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solution, it doesn't work for me... but just by following the below link it worked straight away.
[Have a look at this vim wiki, seems pretty useful](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vim#Make_Vim_restore_cursor_position_in_files)

Comment: You might want to include the essential points of that link in your answer - if arch changes their wiki's format, you might have an answer that makes no sense.

Comment: What JG said. Also, please be more specific than "the above solution", since the answers change order as they are voted upon.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the permission and ownership on your ~/.viminfo file.  If you had earlier accessed vim via a "sudo -s" or something it's possible that vim cannot write to this file.  You might have to chown it back to your group and id.

Answer (score -2):

The [vim-lastplace](https://github.com/dietsche/vim-lastplace/) plugin does exactly what you want (I am the author). It improves on the above accepted answer / code snippet by handling commit messages intelligently. If you have debian-testing you can apt-get install vim-lastplace to quickly try it out.